# Large Data Export from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, csv, amazon-s3, export

We tried using Data Export for Oracle SQL Developer, but it is taking very long (more than 4 hours and still running) to do the export.

Would anyone have suggestion for faster data download from Oracle for large data sources?

Ultimately we are looking to export from Oracle to Amazon S3. Usually we export the files to CSV and then upload the data to S3.

Comment: What is "large" in terms of, say, GB of data?  What is your session waiting on?  My guess is that you're running SQL Developer on a client machine and most of your wait events are network related because you're maxing out the bandwidth between client and server.  Can you run the export on the server (either running SQL Developer on the server machine or generating files via `utl_file` or running Tom Kyte's SQL Unloader utility on the server)?  Then you're not dependent on the network connection between client and server.

Comment: We don't have server access, unfortunately. If the network is the issue and we dont have acess to server then are we stuck?

Comment: If the network is the bottleneck and you can't remove the bottleneck, you may be stuck.  It's possible that changing the fetch size in SQL Developer would have an impact but unless you're on a really slow WAN, it's unlikely to be a huge impact.

Answer (score 0):

I would download the Oracle database tools for windows and use export (exp.exe) to do any large processing. Putting the direct=y option in will bypass the sql evaluation stage and increase throughput tremendously. Also export is more efficient with network traffic as it buffers data which you can set as shown.

```
exp user/pwd@tnsname file=file.dmp direct=y buffer=10000000
```

You can then use the equivilent import tool (imp.exe) to import the data back up.

```
imp user/pwd@tnsname file=file.dmp
```

There are many options to both tools and a good starting point is here:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ